Access to device APIs and features in mobile cross-platform development
I'm designing a new mobile application and one of the initial considerations is whether choose a native or cross-platform mobile application development.
From a research I did, it seems like the main advantage that cross-platform development has over native development is the development time and cost advantage.
However, it was already mentioned that during the cross-platform development I may encounter problems with integrations with the device APIs and features.
My application is required to include features like GPS, SMS, Calls, Access to file system, etc.
Right now I'm in a direction to choose native development process.
So my question is - What kind of problems have you encountered during cross-platform development in terms of integrations with the device itself, and your personal opinion about this subject.
Thanks.

On iOS you don't have access to sms or call details, so maybe research what you want to do before starting to make sure it is possible. In general cross platform tools will have access to native APIs, but you may need to write specific code for the two platforms to account for the differences
